# Use of "of" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is use of "of" in the following sentences correct grammatically?

> It can be easily understand that one **of** losses **of** turbine (or
>   turbomachinery) is due to blade profile.

Comment: There are several mistakes in the sentence, but the usage of 'of' is probably correct. Can you explain a little more about what it actually means? For example, does 'loss' relate to loss of efficiency... or do people misplace turbines? Is it just one turbine, or many turbines, or are you talking about turbines in general?

Comment: 1. yes ..loss related to efficiency.
2. i am talking about turbine in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your sentence, with corrections to several minor points of grammar. Written like this, the first **of** is OK, but the second should be replaced by **in**.

> It can be easily underst**ood** that one of **the** losses of turbine**s** (or turbomachinery) is due to blade profile.

The sentence is still very difficult to understand, for two reasons.

First, the principal meaning of **loss** is no longer having (or having the use of) something. It sounds like somebody is stealing turbines, or they are breaking.

Second, if we do understand loss to mean inefficiency, we think of it as something uncountable: we can talk about a proprtion of it, for example "10% of the losses are due to...", but we cannot talk about it as several countable pieces "one of the losses is due to". It would therefore be better to say "one of the **causes** of loss is..", because **causes** are countable. If we do this, **due to** is not longer required.

A better way to write the sentence would therefore be:

> It can be easily understood that one of the causes of reduced efficiency [in/of] [turbines/turbomachinery] is blade profile.

Answer (score 1):

At with your [most recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108033/use-of-at-and-in-in-a-sentences-together), you are missing an article.  "The" is required in front of "losses":

> one of **the** losses of turbomachinery ...

Otherwise, it's not entirely clear what you mean in this sentence, but grammatically, the sentence is not too far off.  Again, there are more natural ways to say what I guess you are trying to say:

> One of the *reasons* for the loss of turbomachinery is (poorly aligned) blade profile.
>
> One of the *causes* of turbine failure is (poorly maintained) blade profile.
>
> One of the *factors* that cause the loss of a turbine is (an incorrectly installed) blade profile.